# Android Studio 3.1.3 No preview of Items?

Tags: android-studio

I Installed Android Studio 3.1.3 today yesterday and started using it. But There is no Preview of Items such button TextView and other components it is showing in the list but there is no preview available.

The Build Version is : AI-173.4819257.

Here is the ScreenShot.

[image]

Comment: Does it appear when you enter blueprint view?

Comment: try to File->Invalidate caches/restart and then file->sync project with gradle files

Comment: @AlexYates no the bug always there. Changing view won't help.

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos thanks for suggestion, I already tried it but the problem remains same. but changing the `appcompat` version solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems like bug in `AppCompat` latest version.

Change `AppCompat` library version in `Gradle` :

**From**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

**To**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

It Works !

**Edit**

Well this problem seems to exists till now on 16 august 2018.
So This is what i am doing :

Change The `AppCombat` library version in `Gradle` to either `27.1.1` or `28.0.0-alpha1` at design time and at `Build` change Version to the latest.