# Can´t see UI Preview on Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio

i´m using Android Studio 3.1.3 Build #AI-173.4819257 and i have the problem, that i can´t see UI Elements on Preview while using the Designer mode.

Did you have any ideas how i can solve this?

[Can´t see UI Elements on Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wurI0.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168877/android-studio-3-1-3-no-preview-of-items

Comment: I try this and it´s not working.

Answer (score 0):

Is solved. I found an other question on stackoverflow, where is the same problem, and a User mentioned that´s a bug in Android Studio 3.1.3